# When creating service from command prompt with command sc create, how to specify service name to install if assembly contains multiple services

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have 3 services in a single assembly(NotificationServices.exe)

1. SystemNotificationService
2. PlannedNofiticationService
3. DynamicNotificationService

when I create service from command prompt with command `sc create`, how do I specify service name that I want to install.

I have installed services with installer and these are installed perfectly! but I want to create another instance of every service for that I created a copy of installation directory and trying to create service from command `sc create` but I couldn't understand how do I specify service name in following command

```
sc create SystemNotificationService2 binPath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Notification - 2\NotificationServices.exe" 
DisplayName= "System Notification Serice - 2"
```

Comment: The service executable tells the Service Control Manager the names of the service(s) that it includes.  You can't just create additional instances, unless you explicitly designed the service to allow this.  I'm not sure whether .NET-based services are capable of providing this functionality, I suspect they are not.

Answer (score -1):

```
sc create SystemNotificationService2 binPath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Notification - 2\NotificationServices.exe"
```